# probability to finding an answer in a book

Tags: probability

> An answer to a question can be in 5 books, the probability that the answer is in a book at library 1 is $\frac{1}{3}$, else the answer is in the left 4 book in library 2 (same likelihood).
>   
>   What is the probability that the answer is in the book at library 1 if you check 1 book out of the 4 that are in library 2 and it wasn't there?

How should I approach this?

Comment: What have your tried?  To get started, I suggest a simpler question:  one book in library #1, two books in library #2.  $\frac{1}{3}$ probability that the answer is in any particular book.  Given that you unsuccessfully try a book in library #2, now find the probability that the answer is in library 1.

Comment: That "same likelihood" makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I believe the OP means that each of the four books in library #2 are equally likely to contain the answer.  I agree it is unclear as written.

Comment: Yes that was the meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the conditional probability given that the answer was not in 1 book at library 2, using the fact that $P(A|B) =\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$.

If the probability of finding the answer in library 2 is $\frac{2}{3}$, and there are 4 books at library 2, then the probability of finding the answer in a given book at library 2 would be $\frac{2/3}{4} = \frac{1}{6}$. Therefore, the probability of **not** finding the answer in 1 checked book at library 2 is $$
1-P(\text{finding answer in 1 checked book at library 2}) = 1-\frac{1}{6} = \frac{5}{6}$$

Then,

\begin{align*}
P(\text{at library 1} | \text{not in 1 book checked at library 2}) &= \dfrac{P(\text{at library 1}\cap \text{not in 1 book checked at library 2})}{P(\text{not in one book checked at library 2})} \\
&= \dfrac{{1/3}}{{5/6}} \\
&= \frac{6}{15} = \frac{2}{5}
\end{align*}

Comment: why P(not in one book at library 2)=$\frac{5}{6}$ and not less?

Comment: @gbox Sorry I used rather poor terminology, see my edit. The probability that the answer is not in the one book checked at library 2 is $\frac{5}{6}$.

Comment: Still, if it is just probability of $\frac{2}{3}$ to find it there shouldn't it be less than $\frac{5}{6}$

Comment: If the probability of finding the answer in library 2 is $\frac{2}{3}$, and there are 4 books at library 2, then the probability of finding the answer in a given book at library 2 would be $\frac{2/3}{4} = \frac{1}{6}$. Then the probability that it is not in that given book is $1-\frac{1}{6} = \frac{5}{6}$. That is, assuming each of the 4 books at library 2 is equally likely to contain the answer (_which is what I gathered from your question_)

Comment: I always think it is helpful to work geometrically, if you can.  In this case, book A (the Library #1 book) takes up 1/3 of the available area (so to speak).  Each of books C, D,E, and F take up 1/6 of the available area.  You exclude book C, say.  You now have only 5/6 of the area left, but the region you removed was disjoint from the region covered by A.  Thus A the portion A covers of the surviving region is $\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{\frac{5}{6}}$ = $\frac{2}{5}$.

This is the entirely equivalent to the algebraic calculation, but perhaps intuition works better this way?

Comment: @lulu Definitely a matter of preference, given my area of study I seem to introduce basic set theory wherever i can :)

Comment: What I cant understand is why it is $\frac{5}{6}$ and not $\frac{5}{6}*\frac{2}{3}$ as its portion from the first deviation

Comment: @gbox I added further explanation, please see my edit, let me know if it is more clear.

Comment: @gbox...Perhaps the Library aspect is unhelpful.  Suppose you just had 5 books on your shelf.  {A,B,C,D,E} .  the answer you seek is in one of them.  Now, you decide that the probability the answer lives in Book A is $\frac{1}{3}$  and that the probability it lives in B,C,D, or E is $\frac{1}{6}}$.  Now, it's clear that the probability that the answer is NOT in book C is 1 - $\frac{1}{6}$ = $\frac{5}{6}$, no?  The $\frac{2}{3}$ never even appears.  But this is exactly the situation you have (if we pretend your shelf stretches between two libraries!).

Comment: in 1−P(finding answer in 1 checked book at library 2) why dont $1=\frac{2}{3}$? if you get my meaning

Comment: @gbox Because we subtract the probability from the entire probability space, which is evidently 1. If you are looking for the probability of something not occurring, you're going to want to be subtracting it from 1.

Comment: @DonkeyKong but don't we need to take into account the P(the answer is in library) 1 =$\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: @gbox, see my comment from a few minutes ago.  I think the libraries are a red herring.  Think about it as just a set of 5 books (one more likely to contain the answer than any of other 4).

Comment: @lulu Yes that what I mean, I thought I am going crazy

Comment: @gbox. to make the calculation entirely explicit, imagine you had six dots.  The first two represent book A, and we have one dot for each of the other books.  One dot is special in some way.  Each dot is equally likely to be special.  you check the dot corresponding to book C and see that it is ordinary.  You now have 5 dots left, 2 of which are attached to book A.  thus the probability  that the special one is in Book A  is $\frac{2}{5}$.